# Android Bluetooth Check if bonded Device is nearby without connecting

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm searching for a possibility to check if an already bonded device is nearby.
I can't use the startdiscovery-method, because the device isn't discoverable all the time.
Also i can't try to connect, because the device ist already connected with another Device.
Any solutions how to check if the bonded Bluetoothdevice is nearby without connecting?